Output a string to the terminal as though a user had typed it
In rust how can I output a string as though a user had just typed it? i.e. after the prompt.
Example: suppose my program is called "my_command" and it echos the string "echo hi". This is the desired output:
$ my_command
$ echo hi
# user can now just hit enter and it will run "echo hi"

Background: I'm trying to write a cli tool to recall useful commands. I want it to recall a particular command and write it to the prompt, so I can just hit enter to run it.

You can't, unless you're writing a shell or hook into it, only it can. But for that we'd need to know which shell you're trying to write this for.

@cafce25 I'm currently using zsh on MacOS

You can use ANSI escape codes to get a lot of control over what the terminal displays. Then you can manually erase a character when a user types a backspace

ANSI.SYS bombs, here we come!

You can look at how fzf does it. In short: they define a shell function that calls their program, retrieve its output and injects it properly in the shell.

On Linux at least (and possibly on other POSIX systems as well) you can use the TIOCSTI ioctl(). It will only work for the controlling terminal of the current process (unless the calling user has the CAP_SYS_ADMIN on Linux). The following code works fine for me:
use std::{thread::sleep, time::Duration};

fn main() {
    if unsafe { libc::fork() } == 0 {
        sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
        for c in "ls -l".bytes() {
            unsafe {
                libc::ioctl(0, libc::TIOCSTI, &c);
            }
        }
    }
}

Forking and sleeping isn't strictly required, but makes the output look a lot nicer, since the main process can exit, and the child process can give the shell some time to write the prompt, so the new input appears where you'd expect it.
